# MS Access: Possible to bind checkbox value to an attribute of object instance?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

Perhaps someone can give me an advice how i could solve the following problem.

Is there simple solution to "bind" an instance attribut of an object to an element of my form. Of course it could be also solved by triggering the `checkbox_Click()` callback, but at the moment i'm not very happy to with this solution.

For example:

Form Load - Object Init:

```
Dim handlecontact As ClsHandleContact

Private Sub Form_Load()
    ''' init new model handler '''
    Set handlecontact = New ClsHandleContact

    ''' bind attribute of instance to element of form '''
    Me!CheckBox.Bind(handlecontact.boolean_attribut)
End Sub
```

Class ClsHandleContact:

```
Public boolean_attribut As Boolean

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    ''' False by init '''
    boolean_attribut = False
End Sub
```

If an user checks in, i would expect an update of my underlying object instance. Is there an official and supported way to realize this kind of `bind`ing ?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using `WithEvents` to set this up.  Here's a quick tutorial to get you started:

Create a form with a checkbox named `Check0`.  Set `Check0`'s *After Update* property to `[Event Procedure]`.  In the form's code module:

```
Dim handlecontact As clsHandleContact

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Set handlecontact = New clsHandleContact
    Set handlecontact.MyCheckBox = Me.Check0    
End Sub
```

And in the `clsHandleContact` class module:

```
Public WithEvents MyCheckBox As CheckBox

Private Sub MyCheckBox_AfterUpdate()
    MsgBox "The value of the checkbox is now: " & MyCheckBox.Value
End Sub
```